# Change other table view cell's data when selecting one of them

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When I tap on a table view cell I need to change another cell's detail label text. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stored **indexPath** for selected row. You can put a condition in **cellForRow** about same.

Here is sort example:

Declare variable in .h file:

```
int selectedIndexPath;
```

.m

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
     {
           [super viewDidLoad];
           // So it won't show any select for the first time
           selectedIndexPath = -1;
           [tableView reloadData];
     }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        int currentRow = (int)indexPath.row;
        if(currentRow == selectedIndexPath)
        {
            // Show your base cell
        }
        else
        {
            // Show detail cell
        }
    }
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        selectedIndexPath = (int)indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadData];

    }
```